# Lightning Component Action Won't Rerender Component if Called Again

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have a component that loads a list of Property objects from Apex and displays them in an Aura:iteration.

My JS controller is really basic:

```
getProperties_JS: function(component, event, helper){
    var searchFilters = helper.setSearchFilters(component);
    var getProps = component.get('c.getProperties');
    getProps.setParams({
        filters:searchFilters
    });
    getProps.setCallback(this,function(theList){
        if(theList.getState() === 'SUCCESS'){
            var r = theList.getReturnValue();
            console.log('getReturnValue',r);
            component.set('v.properties',r.properties);
        }else if (theList.getState() === "ERROR") {
            console.log('ERROR: ' , theList.getError());
            $A.log("Errors", theList.getError());
        }else{
            console.log('no errors caught - but nothing returned.');
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(getProps);
},
```

My Component is really basic as well:

```
<aura:component controller="PropertyListViewController">
    <aura:attribute name="properties" type="Property[]" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.getProperties_JS}"/>

    <button onclick="{!c.getProperties_JS}">Refetch</button>

    <aura:iteration items="{!v.properties}" var="p">
        <c:PropertyTile propertyRecord="{!p}" />
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

So when the page first loads, it gets all the data as expected.  When I click Refetch, I can see in the console that I'm getting all the filtered results back (I've simplified the code here a bit for brevity), and I can see that there are no errors in javascript nor in Apex.  However, instead of the list rerendering with the new values, it just goes blank.

Additionally, once I click the button, all my other functionality on the page essentially breaks.  Example: I have some ui:menus on the page that, after I refetch the data, will no longer close once I open them.

Update: it appears that once there is data in the view, trying to replace that data breaks everything. I set it so that the data won't load at all until I click the button, and it works the first time I click and get data into the view. Then when I click again and refetch, it all goes blank.

Comment: Update: it appears that once there is data in the view, trying to replace that data breaks everything.  I set it so that the data won't load at all until I click the button, and it works the first time I click and get data into the view.  Then when I click again and refetch, it all goes blank.